# Django - как лучше построить "динамические" блоки?

Tags: django

Вопрос в следующем.
Есть набор сущностей, которые требуется показать, если не на всех - то на многих страницах (при этом не все они имеют непосредственое отношение к показываемой странице. Такие себе виджеты).
При этом этот набор меняется - хардкодить их в верстке, само собой, не вариант.
Также, ввиду того, что они не имеют отношения к предмету страницы - грузить их из view-а не хотелось бы.

Решил примерно таким образом - создал своё приложение, которое :

- создаёт свой тег
- при его "рендеринге" - обращается к переданной функции (грубо говоря - `{% view_block tagcloud %}` вернёт результат `tags.views.tagcloud()`) и возвращает её результат

Но, возможно, таки велосипед, или же есть лучший подход? Код тут - https://github.com/alex4321/django-template-blocks

Comment: Чем тебя assignment_tag не устраивает? Какие сущности если всякие менюхи и тому подобное, то assignment_tag самое то.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [django-streamfield](https://github.com/raagin/django-streamfield).